# Simulation on Simetrix ends before end time

Tags: simulation, pspice

I have this problem, I'm simulating on Simetrix a buck converter circuit, with multiple combinations of parallel diodes to source Vin and MOSFETS piloted by an arbitrary PWM (in this case it is at 40%) and I'm facing this weird problem: I can't seem to end the simulation.
[image: Simulation]
[image: PWM that creates problem]

I saw that this is the first 10us of the simulation, here's details of the simulation check:
[image: Simulation check]

I'm pretty sure that the first 10us of the simulation are correct, since checking the same circuit, but with a duty cycle of the PWM at about 80%, circuit works fine! I even tried to zoom in at the first 10us to check if in the correct simulation, the curve goes similar to the unfinished simulation, and I guess they really are similar:
[image: Simulation working]
[image: PWM that works]
[image: Simulation working WITH ZOOM AT 10us ON PLOT]

So as you can see, it's like the simulation on the 40% duty-cycle-pwm is going as expected, and then boom, for whatever reason, simulation ends at 10us, instead of keeping it active up to 1ms.

Help!

I tried changing Trise and Tfall of the PWM and somewhat helps to increase/decrease simulation time, but this is something that should not interfere with simulation time... I mean why should it?
I tried zooming out on the plot in the unfinished simulation, to check if it was a GUI problem of not zooming out correctly, and sadly it wasnt, there were no points at all after those 10us.